# Stack Overflow Careers Profile using our Amazon reading list

Tags: feature-request, jobs, list, amazon, kindle

It would really be great if you could pull my kindle reading list off of my amazon profile. this would save me so much time from having to re-enter my information all the time. Linkedin has the same problem :(

Comment: Why do you need this? What will your Kindle reading list say about you to prospective employers?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, we already have the books feature, I think this is just being proposed as an easier/faster way to populate and maintain a curated list there.

Comment: @NicolBolas the reason I bring this up, is that you currently have an Amazon public profile which already lets you manage private / public books and notes as well as highlights. In this profile a book starts off as private and is not visible to anyone. Once you set it to public it is then viewed by anyone who finds your profile. https://kindle.amazon.com/profile/Alexandre-Brisebois/1046735

Answer (score 2):

I am actually a huge fan of this, to the point of having looked into seeing what tools were available from amazon to go as far as even showing how far you are into the books you are reading.

Why am I a huge fan of this?  Two main reasons:

1. Because your reading list tells perspective employers what types of things you enjoy learning, possibly how long it takes you to get through certain topics or as a means to evaluate how much free time you have/spend reading.

   This obviously is not an exact science, but it can provide insight into the habits of candidates and provide a basis for a large array of interview questions.  At the bare minimum it would show that you are actively learning things and not just that you have learned things in the past.  And of course you can lie about the books you've read currently by just adding any book you want, so it's always up to the employer to validate your knowledge in an interview.
2. Because I use my profile as more of a personal landing page/business card than as a direct way to get a new job (I mean, I'm pretty happy with the one I have).  As such, the value of my profile is not limited to searching for jobs.

   Optimally I'd love it if the display had some functionality where you could drill down on a specific book and see where they started and where they stopped each day throughout reading the entire book.  That's the kind of eye candy that I really find interesting and fun to play with.

When looking this up initially a few weeks back I found that amazon doesn't really like to share that kind of in depth data (assuming they even track that themselves) and nothing is available currently from Amazon which supports this functionality (at least where I looked).